# How to increase editor font size?

Tags: android-studio

Font size in Android Studio editor seems to be too small.

How can I make the font size larger?

Answer (score 301):

Done, you can try this(on Mac):
Preferences --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts, in the right side, then click "save as...", this will create a new Scheme, we name it such as "Custom", then all fields become to editable, font, space, color, etc.

Comment: There is no option for "Preferences" that I can find. Perhaps the answer is outdated?

Comment: @ineedahero, In mac there is a horizontal menu bar on top of screen. the leftmost menu is an apple icon. click on it and you will see the Preferences.

Comment: This approach *only* sets the font size for the Editor. If you are looking to make the fonts larger in the project panel and such, you will need to use the "Appearance" page and choose the "Override default fonts" option. Which Mosh Feu said below as well

Answer (score 221):

## Temporarily adjust the font size

Go to Settings (or Preferences in Mac) > Editor > General > Change font size (Zoom) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Mouse Wheel
OR Press "<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>" for mac.

[image]

This will allow you to quickly modify the font size whenever you want. However, the font will get reset to the default size the next time you start Android Studio. (The Control+Mouse Wheel functionality will not get reset, though. You only need to do this once.)

## Permanently change the default font size

Go to Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Font. Click "Save As..." and choose a new scheme name. Then change the font size and say OK. This will be the default size every time you open Android Studio now.

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio 4.1 on Windows 10 : [File] > [Settings] > [Editor] > [Font] > Size : 13

Answer (score 118):

Acoustics answer works, on windows it would be File --> Settings --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts then save as, name it something then you can edit all the fields you want.

Comment: At this time 2021, File -> Setting -> search for Color Scheme Font

Answer (score 37):

Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)--> Apprarance-->Override default fonts by(not recommended):

then change Size to 16+.

Comment: this one only modify the IDE menu font size but not the code display font size...

Answer (score 24):

By default, Android Studio doesn't allow the normal CTRL + Mouse scroll to zoom in or out.  You can enable it in the settings, though it seems its location has changed over time.  Mac users are well documented in other answers, but I use Windows.

For Windows users in Android Studio 3.4, you go to `File -> Settings -> General`, then check the box `Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel`.  See below:

[image]

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Ctrl + Shift + A  --> enter Font size --> select Increase Font Size

this will open Dialog for Enter Action or option Name

enter Fonte Size it will show selection for  select Increase Font Size

Done :)

Comment: This does not increase for all editors, only the active editor is affected

Answer (score 19):

I have the latest version of Android Studio installed (3.6.1).

I navigated to: **File->Settings->Editor->Font**. The dialog displays a warning message (yellow triangle) indicating that the Font is **defined in the color scheme**.

(Editing the Font here had no effect.)

[image: Editor Font]

I clicked on the dialog's warning message link.

This navigated to: **File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Color Scheme Font**.

(Now I could edit the Font for my current scheme.)

[image: Editor Color Scheme Color Scheme Font]

Comment: I noticed **Editor->Font** size settings no effect if selected **Classic Light** scheme(other scheme no issue) unless enable+use mouse zoom or **Color Scheme Font** size.

Answer (score 12):

As a temporary tweak ( not permanent )

On Mac you would need to create your own shortcuts ..

Its easy. my set:

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel-up</kbd> for increase font size

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Wheel-down</kbd> for decreasing font size

Prefernces => Keymap => Increase Font size/decrease Font size/Reset Font size

[image]

!! Don't forget to click Apply Button at Bottom Right before closing Settings Dialog otherwise changes will not get applied & you will need to do this setup again.

Good luck,'.

Answer (score 10):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font.

Answer (score 9):

**Permanently change the default font size for *UI elements***

Go to Settings ("Preferences" on Mac) > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance. Tick the checkbox "Override default fonts by (not recommended)". Then change the font size and hit "OK"
[image]

Answer (score 5):

For MacBook Users:

[image]

To change font size:

```
Select **Android Studio** menu (which is present next to Apple icon)-->Preferences--->Editor-->Font-->Size(give size)-->ok
```

To zoom in and out in Editor:

```
Select **Android Studio** menu -->Editor-->General-->change font size (zoom) with command and mouse wheel-->ok
```

Answer (score 5):

Very Simple .

Go to File then Settings then Select Editor then Font and change the size .

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible ways of doing this:

### **1. Setting a custom shortcut for change font size:**

> Preferences -> KeyMap -> Editor Action -> Dcrease Font size/Increase
> Font size

And set a shortcut for each purpose. 
NOTE: you can set a mouse shortcut as well in a custom shortcut. 
This custom shortcut feature is really helpful when are you are migrating from another code editor and is habitual to the use of another shortcut.

[image: Zoom in/out feature custom shortcut setting android studio]

---

### **2. Set the zoom in and zoom out to mouse scroll with control pressed if you are a windows user and command pressed if you are a macOS user.**

> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Mark checked Option -> Change Font
> size with Command + mouse wheel

[image: Font Zoom In/Out Editor Window android studio]

Answer (score 4):

In latest version of android studio ,We can change the appearance settings like font size and font style using following  steps
Android Studio ---->preference--font

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to search in preferences (android studio IDE > preferences). 
In aptana studio it works like this making smaller: CMD and -, use CMD shift and =. 
Works?

Answer (score 3):

ok I reached to this solution by the help of two people who answered above, Mosh Feu and Suragch    `First open settings (ctrl+alt+s), second go to Editor->General->Fonts->Size.`

Answer (score 2):

In mac book ,you can use two fingers to zoom in(increase font size) or zoom out for decrease font size, like when we zoomed image in mobilephone.

Comment: wouldn't this only apply to users with touch-screens? also if it's just zoom, it's not a change of font size, it will also enlarge everything else, no?

Comment: No, you can use two fingers on your trackpad of macbook.
You will can change of font size :)

Answer (score 2):

For WINDOWS users: `FILE-->SETTingS-->EDITOR-->FONT.`

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Easy Way 
Press **Double Shift** and then type increase --> Click **Increase Font Size** and then your editor change the font

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because of my 4K screen too thin to read. Then u need to change from monospace In my case it was because of my 4K screen too thin to read. Then u need to change from **Monospaced** to **Consolas**.

Settings --> Color Scheme Font --> Font --> **Consolas**

Answer (score 1):

Works as of Arctic Fox update on macOS.

To change the font size of the IDE itself:

Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Check "Use custom font" and then increase the font size.

...

To change the font size of the Editor:

Android Studio > Preferences >  Editor > Font > change size

Answer (score 1):

Sharing as this does not seem to be mentioned:

From the trackpad: `cmd` + `2 finger scroll towards you` to zoom out

Answer (score 1):

This is what font setting looks like in 2024 (Android Studio Hedgehog).

From File > Settings > Editor > Fonts

[image]

Meanwhile, to have freedom of using the Ctrl + Mouse wheel
Its File > Settings > Editor > General

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have to be more careful when doing this. For the first time I have changed the font size of menu by mistake instead of font. First create your own scheme by going to File-->Settings-->Colors & Fonts and then you can make changes to your own scheme. The final procedure is to go to settings(File-->Settings) and then select `Editor` and `Colors & Fonts`in the left bar menu. Then select the arrow on the left side of `Colors & Fonts` and then select `Font` in the left menu bar. You will get options to change your values. Remember you can only change values to your own sheme.

Answer (score 0):

**Update all font sizes**

Go to Appearances & Behavior > Appearances, checkmark custom font and update the size field.
That will change all font sizes except for the editor one.
Go to Editor > Font and update the size field. That will change the font of the editor.