# Android Studio Editor Font Sizing

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

Is there any way to make the editor text larger in Android Studio?

I go to Settings>Editor>Colors&Fonts>Font where I find "Size:12". However, I'm unable to change the value for the size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase the font in Android Studio in Windows 8 or Mac book pro retina](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590216/how-to-increase-the-font-in-android-studio-in-windows-8-or-mac-book-pro-retina)

Comment: Just a note for future generations, the Settings menu is inside `File` tab and not inside `Tools`. You should go: `File -> Settings -> Editor`

Answer (score 167, accepted):

They didn't make this very obvious, did they?

All you have to do is click the "Save As" button to create a new profile. You can't change the font because you can't overwrite the default profiles.

Comment: Bah! I had a feeling it was something as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: This is terrible UX. I would generally expect to edit something _then_ save it. Thank you for explaining pat IntelliJ's poor UX.

Comment: No, they didn't make it very obvious. This is pretty counterintuitive... still, thanks for clearing that out.

Comment: Wow, as of now this question has almost 31k views. The UI was so bad that they confused 31,000 *programmers*!

Answer (score 53):

If creating a custom setting doesn't help:

**Click on File > Settings > Editor** and check the field: 
*Change font-size with CTRL + Mouse Wheel*.
[image: screenshot]
Worked for me.

Comment: changing font size with mouse wheel is quite helpful, but what i need is i want font size like 13, not 12 or 14, and if you change this size from settings, it will only get applied to current active tab, is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 30):

Extending the answer above, for Windows:
  1. Go to File > Settings ...
  2. Modify the settings shown below

[image: Font size in Android Studio --- on Windows]

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Android Studio (version 0.5.2) then this applies:

Click on [File][Settings], and under the "IDE Settings" area (left side Pane), choose "Appearance".

On the right side (the 'Appearance Settings') check the CheckBox called "Override default fonts by (not recommended)" and then the "Size" choice will un-grey and you can choose a new size using either the PullDown or by typing a number. Double check that the number is reasonable (not too large).

Click [Apply] to see the result of your choice and ensure that it is readable before choosing [OK] and dismissing the Settings Panel.

**Cautions:** Since Android Studio is still in Beta (a new Program) choosing too small or too large a Font, or choosing one that the Editor does not agree with, may make Text either unreadable or worse (cause a crash).

This is likely why the Setting says "*not recommended*". You do not want to have to edit the Program's settings with a Hex Editor if you make a mess by setting the Fonts to 144 Points instead of just 14 -- the Menu line would be huge.

A small increase in the Font size should be OK but be careful not to make Text so large that it can not fit in the area that was reserved for it (not just in the Editor but also the "Main Menu" and the "Info Bar" (at the bottom).

**Note:** The 'Edit Window' Text is smaller than all the other Text by one size but all Text is controlled by the one Setting. Making the 'Edit Window' Text too big is very likely to cause problems elsewhere since all the other Text is larger than what is shown in the 'Edit Window'.

Answer (score 4):

### Keymap

There is nothing wrong with the other answers but this one shows how to **map the font sizing to a keyboard shortcut**. One can then use `Cmd/=` and `Cmd/-` (or `Ctrl/=`, `Ctrl-`) to manage the font sizing. You can choose any key combination you like but note the conflicts message that appears when you select a keyboard shortcut (just to be sure that it makes sense in your use-case).

Go to Preferences (Settings in Windows) Menu and select the Keymap section title on the left. On the right sections' search box, type in `font`. You will find several entries including `Increase Font Size` and `Decrease Font Size`. You can double click each of these to add a keyboard shortcut.

[image: keymap]

For mine, I chose `Cmd/=` and `Cmd/-` as my shortcuts respectively. You will be prompted with an option to `Leave` or `Remove` conflicts. In my case, I chose to leave the conflicts in place as they are never likely to be loaded at the same time.

*Double-click to add keymap*

[image: add]

*Enter key combination and note any conflicts*

[image: opt1]

*Choose how to handle conflicts*

> NB: If you choose `Leave`, conflicts remain ~ but may not matter if they
>   are not loaded at the same time. If you choose `Remove` then the original
>   keyboard shortcuts are removed (use with care).

[image: leave]

### Nota Bene

Another useful keymap on font sizing is `Reset Font Size`, which puts things back to the default setting. This option shows up when you search the Keymap in preferences for `font`. In my case, I chose `Cmd/Shift/0` so that I would avoid the commonly used `Cmd\0` shortcut that opens the Messages window.

*Reset Font Size*

[image: reset]

**Valid as of Android Studio 1.5.1**

### FYI

> A different method to change the font sizes is to open the Actions
>   menu and search for `font`. When found then double click on the
>   `increase/decrease font size` choices. On the Mac, I access actions
>   menu using the `Cmd/Shift/A` shortcut or under `Help` menu, choose
>   `Find Actions`.

Answer (score 3):

A nice feature is:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General

On top there is a section "Mouse"

You can click on the "Change font size (ZOOM) with CTRL+Mouse wheel"

So you can change the size on demand.

Answer (score 2):

In MacBook Android Studio ->[image]

Select Preferences... ->

[image]Click on Save As.. ->Give any name [image]-> OK -> then select Scheme -> and you given name[image] every option Editable

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Settings > Editor*, expand the Editor tree, go to *Color & Fonts* expand that tree and find *Font*, at the top select the theme you want to change fonts for and then change the font under *Editor Font*

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have fixed it now. I'm using Android Studio 3.0, and I'm able to modify default scheme.

Just open `Settings > Editor > Colors&Fonts > Font`, enter the desired font size in field "Size" and click "Apply" button, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto   Files | Settings | Appearance & Behavior --> appearance --> scroll down mouse you will find presentation mode change the font size .

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue but it was due to changed font family. I had to specify Font size for specific Font Family I was currently using. Got to Settings > Font > Click Current Editor font...[image]

It will open Color Scheme > Color Scheme Font. Specify Font size here
[image]