# Android studio pixelated preview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

After updating Android studio to version 3.1.2 an issue popped up where the preview image is, pixelated/blurry. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

This is how the image is rendered

[image]

Comment: Did you tried in real device?

Comment: Yes I have and it worked normal but I've been so used to using it feels wrong.

Comment: Has anybody solved this issue? facing the same.. preview is pixelated.

Comment: I have been searching but I've not been able to solve it.

Comment: I can confirm this on 3.1.4.

Comment: I found this link to throw some light on this issue: https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot#high-density_displays

Answer (score 12):

I have encountered the same problem in Android Studio 3.3 but fortunately I've managed to find a solution. You have to go to "Help" and click on "Edit Custom Properties". It might ask you to generate a file if it doesn't already exist. Once this properties file is made, you will need to write "hidpi=false" (no quotations). Save it and restart Android Studio. When you open it again , you still need to do one thing: go to File then Settings, type font in search box, select font from editor then change the size of font to 15. (or what ever size you prefer). That's all.

Comment: i am sorry to hear that... but at me worked with no problems :(

Comment: I'm on Android Studio 2020.3.1 and just doing the hidpi=false part solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Fixed Preview but IDE Text size is too small and not affecting even after font size change.

Comment: Font size issue was resolved y this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119401/8663316

Comment: not working on 
android studio Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 28, 2022

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure weather it will work for your scenario. I had a issue with icon pixels and I followed this.

I hope it will help you.

Create a drawable-xxhdpi directory and add all your images in that and try.

NOTE : I'm not sure that this process helps you or not.

[link help you to create drawable-xxhdpi directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294287/android-studio-drawable-folder-how-to-put-images-for-multiple-dpi)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your input. This, however, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem and it is somehow annoying i opened a bug ticket and i will wait for there response here is the ticket link : https://issuetracker.google.com/110463869

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem pretty easy after learning documentation.

You need to change your scale display parameter. Because  Android Studio supports only certain scale. Use 100% or 200% and your design tab in Android  will be sharp again

[image]

Choose "answer is useful" mark)) if it helps you.