# Android Studio Layout Preview Low Resolution

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I have recently updated to `Android Studio 3.3` and have noticed that my layout preview is at a low resolution.

[image]

Is there any solution to fixing this? This issue occurs only with the preview and in the design tab (excluding the blueprint) - running the app is fine.

Thanks

UPDATE: I deleted all of my Android Studio files, including the SDK (which was somehow installed on my other SSD). Then I re-downloaded `Android Studio 3.3` and opened my project, only to find that the issue still remained.

Comment: Working answer by Cristian Babarusi here in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384287/8836263

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio pixelated preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50754524/android-studio-pixelated-preview)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of users are facing problems until now with Android Studio 3.3. I don't think it's a problem with graphic card, maybe they will release a new update fixing the problems in the near future. For the moment would suggest you to work with design/blueprint, and test by running the app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this line to my IDE custom properties:

```
hidpi=false
```

Just go to Help -> Edit Custom Properties (Create new file if it doesn't exits)

Then add the following line and restart your IDE.
[image]