# ANDROID STUDIO font increment of java & xml code

Tags: javascript, xml, android-studio

my code font is very small in .xml & .java. How do I increase the font size?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the font in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590216/how-to-increase-the-font-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the Project and Go to 'settings'. In that go to 'Editor' node. There you can see 'Colors and Fonts' where you can change the font size.
For more info ,visit 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html?search=font

Answer (score 0):

First create your own scheme by going to File-->Settings-->Colors & Fonts and then you can make changes to your own scheme. The final procedure is to go to settings(File-->Settings) and then select Editor and Colors & Fontsin the left bar menu. Then select the arrow on the left side of Colors & Fonts and then select Font in the left menu bar. You will get options to change your values. Remember you can only change values to your own sheme.

This I have done in android studio 2.1.1