# How to change default font size of Quick Documentation?

Tags: android-studio

There is a related question,[How to increase the font size in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590216/how-to-increase-the-font-size-in-android-studio).

But It doesn't increase the font size of Quick Documentation.

Answer (score 7):

1. Open **Quick Documentation** window.
2. Click on cogwheel in the upper-right corner of the **Quick Documentation** window.
   [image: quick documentation window]
3. Move slider.
   [image: quick documentation window]

Or use `Ctrl + Mouse wheel` in **Quick Documentation** window to change the font size.

Comment: that doesn't change the default size. On next restart, the font size remains the same. changes are not preserved across sessions.

Comment: Hmm, my `Android Studio` kept changing between sessions. If I reopen current project, open other project, restart AS, reboot system `Android Studio` saved custom font size in **Quick Documentation** window

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. It keeps resetting after restart. The size was fine in 1.5 but now the font is much larger in 2.2. I wonder if this is a bug