# How to increase the font size in Android Studio (MacOS High Sierra)?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

There is a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590216/how-to-increase-the-font-size-in-android-studio) on this topic. The top answer says to go to "**Preferences --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts**". However in **MacOS High Sierra**, I cannot find "Editor" in the System Preferences panel:

[image: System Preference panel]

The zoom in/out gesture on touchpad works. However I need to do the same for every tab, and when re-opening a closed tab, the previous font size setting is not kept.

Where is the setting that allows me to change the font size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Environment**:

> macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.4)
>
> Android Studio (3.1.3)

## To Increase font size of Source code

Go to **Preferences > Editor > Font** and change font size
OR you can simply search by typing *Font* in search box at top left of `Preferences window`

[image]

## To Increase font size of Android Studio's controls

Go to **Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance** and check the `Override default fonts by(not recommended)` and here  you can set your Android Studio's font size
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realise what went wrong. I should go to "**Android Studio**-->Preferences --> Editor --> Colors & Fonts", not going to Apple logo-->System Preferences.
[Android Studio Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIz09.png)