# Adjust the text size of the Android Studio parameter prompt

Tags: android

When I hold down the CTRL key and place the mouse over the ClassName, it gives me the parameter name of the class. How do I change the size of the text
[image]

Comment: You can change your editor font size, to change editor font size check [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16590216/how-to-increase-editor-font-size#:~:text=Go%20to%20Settings%20%3E%20Editor%20%3E%20Colors,you%20open%20Android%20Studio%20now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of CTRL click, you can hover the cursor on the class name (or press F1) and the popup will have 3 dots in bottom right corner.

From here you can click "Adjust font size" like in picture below.

[image]

Comment: When I pressed F1 on the class, the browser opened and there was no pop-up window

Comment: When I press CTRL and Q on the class, three dots appear，I'm going to use CTRL + Q instead of CTRL + mouse.Thank you

Comment: @jack This probably depends on the current shortcut setup :) Btw I'm glad you solved it.